# Where is my mistake in this complex numpy usage?

Tags: python, numpy

recently I am learning NumPy's usage and I met a question which gives me 3 array:

```
- q: A numpy array of shape (1, K) (queries)
- k: A numpy array of shape (N, K) (keys)
- v: A numpy array of shape (N, 1) (values)
```

and ask me to do sum_i exp(-||q-k_i||^2) * v[i]

My code is:

(np.exp(np.sum((np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)) - k)**2, axis = -1)**0.5 * -1).T.dot(v))[0]

But the value is not correct.

For readability, I explain my previous one-line code as follows:
1.

If anyone knows where is my mistake, please help me, thank you. Stuck on this for a long time.

np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)  // this makes a N line copy of q, for following operation.

(np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)) - k)  // this is just let q - k, making an elementwise, same-size, q-k matrix

np.sum((np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)) - k)**2, axis = -1)**0.5 gives a row-wise L2-norm, so currently we have a (N,1) matrix, each row is the norm of the original q-k[i]

np.exp(np.sum((np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)) - k)**2, axis = -1)**0.5 * -1).T
Then we do exp of its -1 negative, and eventually, dot it with the v, to automatically get the sum.

I tried the np.exp(-np.linalg.norm((np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)) - k), axis=1, ord = 2)).T.dot(v)[0]
aka linalg.norm method, but it does not change...

Comment: Please format you're code properly, otherwise its very hard to read. If a line with 4+ nested statements isn't working, I recommend splitting them up on different lines, assigning each a variable, and printing all their values so you can see which step isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the formula you shared, it takes exponential of **Square** of norm(q-k). You missed the square term. Try this out.

```
    np.exp(np.sum((np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)) - k)**2, axis = -1) * -1).T.dot(v)
```

or

```
    np.exp(-np.linalg.norm((np.tile(q, (np.shape(k)[0], 1)) - k), axis=1, ord = 2)**2).T.dot(v)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is stupid... You are right!